# Data is not inserting using $_SESSION variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, session, syntax, insert

I created a forum and i wanted insert some data into tables in mysql like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
                    topics(topic_subject,
                           topic_date,
                           topic_cat,
                           topic_by)
               VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']) . "',
                           NOW(),
                           " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . ",
                           " . $_SESSION['email'] . "
                           )";
```

and it is giving an error like
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1"

Comment: Output the query and look at it. Looks like you are missing quotes. One place `" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . "`....

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please try with simply with assigning with variable...

```
$topic_subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']);
$topic_cat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']);
$topic_by = $_SESSION['email'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO topics(topic_subject,
                       topic_date,
                       topic_cat,
                       topic_by)
           VALUES('$topic_subject', 
                   NOW(),
                   '$topic_cat', 
                   '$topic_by'
                       )";
```

Comment: I tried that also but  "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`polytechnic`.`topics`, CONSTRAINT `topics_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`topic_by`) REFERENCES `students` (`Email`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)" error comes  , here polytechnic is my database name , topics and students are tables.